# Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364

Tags: php, laravel

How to fix this?

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a
> default value (SQL: insert into `ptcs` (`title`, `details`,
> `duration`, `rewards`, `ad_link`, `hit`, `membership_id`,
> `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Charlie Puth, dfghjkl;', 10, 100,
> http://test.com/, 435, 1, 2021-06-27 18:48:44, 2021-06-27 18:48:44))

Controller:

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'title'=> 'required|max:15',
        'details' => 'required|max:100',
        'duration' => 'required|numeric',
        'membership_id' => 'required',
        'ad_link' => 'required|url',
        'rewards' => 'required|numeric',
         'hit' => 'required|numeric'

    ]);
    $ptc = Ptc::create([

        'title' => $request->title,
        'details' => $request->details,
        'duration' => $request->duration,
        'rewards' => $request->rewards,
        'ad_link' => $request->ad_link,
        'hit' => $request->hit,
        'type' =>1,
        'count' =>0,
        'membership_id' => $request->membership_id,
    ]);

    session()->flash('message', 'The Paid To Click Has Been Successfully Created.');
    Session::flash('type', 'success');
    Session::flash('title', 'Created Successful');


    return redirect()->route('admin.ptcs.index');


}
```

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: can you share your migration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is clear.

Field '`user_id`' doesn't have a default value.

In your `ptcs` table you have `user_id` and it is not have a default value and you're not setting a value for `user_id` in your php side.

```
$ptc = Ptc::create([

        'title' => $request->title,
        'details' => $request->details,
        'duration' => $request->duration,
        'rewards' => $request->rewards,
        'ad_link' => $request->ad_link,
        'hit' => $request->hit,
        'type' =>1,
        'count' =>0,
        'membership_id' => $request->membership_id,
        'user_id' => //Give here an id for testing like 1235
    ]);
```

if your `$request` object has `user_id` set it like others.

```
'user_id' => $request->name_of_your_user_id_parameter
```

According to your comment `user_id` is not fillable for mass assignment.

So on your `Ptc` model class you need something like;

```
class Ptc extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'title', 'description', ... other fields);

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

or on your table schema set a default value or nullable

Comment: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`u797910348_testserver`.`ptcs`, CONSTRAINT `ptcs_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `ptcs` (`title`, `details`, `duration`, `rewards`, `ad_link`, `hit`, `type`, `count`, `membership_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Charlie Puth, dfghjkl;', 10, 100, http://server1.pesobucks.com/, 435, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2021-06-27 19:18:10, 2021-06-27 19:18:10)) ◀

Comment: Make sure you have `user_id` in the fillable property of your `Ptc` model.

Comment: @RandelJohnCabelin That error means the value you trying to insert into the `user_id` column does not exist in the `users` table.